# redirect post id to post full url

Tags: customization, url-rewriting, htaccess, wp-redirect

I use this permalink structure `/%post_id%/%postname%/` in WordPress

the problem is that posts are accessible via `post_id` for example:

```
example.com/1415/how-to-make-a-cookie
```

is accessible with this URL

```
example.com/1415
```

I want to redirect `example.com/1415` to the full post URL.

Comment: I've removed the `htaccess` tag, as this isn't something you can do in `.htaccess` - you'll need to use WordPress.